# Record video from camera parallel to OpenCV processing on android

Tags: java, android, opencv, video, camera

As I now understand, it is not that easy to record a video, processed by OpenCV on android. But is there any possibility to do it parallel: 
- to record video from camera, using standard android tools (MediaRecorder) and
- to process video with OpenCV (mOpenCvCameraView) without saving it?

Thank you once again!

Answer (score 0):

I think, you don' t need to record a video. You shouldn' t it...

You can capture all frame in `onCameraFrame()` method.

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    Mat carrierMatgray = inputFrame.gray();
    // do something 
    Mat carrierMatRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
    return carrierMatRgba;
}
```