# Fastest way to do OpenCV processing and writing video from camera on android?

Tags: android, opencv, android-camera, android-mediacodec

I have seen question [Record video from camera parallel to OpenCV processing on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22860603/record-video-from-camera-parallel-to-opencv-processing-on-android) about similar problem but it not answered.
I see two posibilities:

1. to record video from camera, using standard android tool MediaRecorder and simultaneously process byte[] array with OpenCV in previewCallback.
2. record video with MediaCodec like in Gragika project https://github.com/google/grafika. While recording use glReadPixels from texture and pas it to OpenCV Mat for processing.

What better or maybe exists another approach?

Comment: If you could deliver the frames to both ImageReader and MediaCodec, that would get you software access and hardware encoding without copying bytes unnecessarily. Not possible with the old Camera API, but might be possible with Camera2.

Answer (score 1):

I have worked it out.

For the first way you mentioned:

1. Lock the camera before preparing a MediaRecorder.
2. Relock the camera calling `reconnect()` immediately after mediaRecorder's `start()` method.

However, since API level 14 the camera can be automatically relocked after calling `start()` so actually you don't need to `reconnect()`.

3. Set preview callback. Use `setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer()` and set more than one callback buffer if you want to achieve higher frame rate.

But from my experiments, frames from preview callback and frames recorded by MediaRecorder are asynchronous. So it is hard to guarantee frame synchronization if you need to.

For the second way: You have full control of frames.

Thanks to fadden's project, I succeeded in recording while doing image processing by using MediaCodec to encode video frames from preview callback and passing the preview data to native layer via JNI for image processing with OpenCV.

It should be noted that for real-time efficiency you must do the processing in another thread and ensure synchronization with the encoding thread.

Comment: About first way. It is possible, but need to start listening again after recording (call setPreviewCallback() again after record.start()). It's work on my phone.

Comment: As I understand you write from previewTexture with mediacodec and get bytes[] with previewCallback for OpenCV? Can you say more about "passing the preview data to native layer via JNI" please.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have tried it and it did work. However, it seems to be difficult to guarantee synchronization if you hope the frame you are currently recording using MediaRecorder is the frame from preview callback, as they are asynchronous.

Comment: I encode the byte[] data from preview callback using MediaCodec without using previewTexture. In another thread, I send the preview data to native layer using JNI.

Comment: Is this faster then using previewTexture like in bigflake CameraToMpegTest? I try use it and preview callback for OpenCV at the same time.

Comment: No. Encoding surface directly is much faster.